# Firefox Extention - My simple button masher isn't actually mashing buttons

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm trying to create an extension for my first project but I'm having issues. The purpose of the addon is just to click a button that the user puts into the field. But its not clicking. Doesn't matter what the button says or what I change it to, it wont work. Thank you for any help.
**This is my manifest.json file**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Button Masher",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Automatically clicks a button",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "sidebar_action": {
    "default_title": "Button Masher",
    "default_panel": "sidebar.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "48": "button-48.png"
    }
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage", "tabs", "menus"]
}
```

**This is my content.js**

```
let buttonLabel = "blank";

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
  if (message.command === "clickButton") {
    let spans = document.getElementsByClassName("button-label");
    for (let span of spans) {
      if (span.textContent.includes(buttonLabel)) {
        let clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: false,
          view: window,
        });
        span.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
});

browser.storage.sync.get("buttonLabel", (data) => {
  if (data.buttonLabel) {
    buttonLabel = data.buttonLabel;
  }
});
```

**This is my background.js**

```
let enabled = false;

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
  if (message.command === "start") {
    enabled = true;
  } else if (message.command === "stop") {
    enabled = false;
  }
});

browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (enabled && changeInfo.status === "complete") {
    browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { command: "clickButton" });
  }
});
```

**This is my sidebar.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <label for="buttonLabel">Button label:</label>
    <input type="text" id="buttonLabel" name="buttonLabel">
    <button id="save">Save</button>
    <button id="start">Start</button>
    <button id="stop">Stop</button>
    <button id="exit">Exit</button>
    <script src="sidebar.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**This is my sidebar.js**

```
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let buttonLabel = document.getElementById("buttonLabel").value;
  browser.storage.sync.set({ buttonLabel });
});

document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", () => {
  browser.runtime.sendMessage({ command: "start" });
});

document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", () => {
  browser.runtime.sendMessage({ command: "stop" });
});

document.getElementById("exit").addEventListener("click", () => {
  window.close();
});
```

I tried removing the sidebar to see if that was an issue but it wasn't. I tried changing permissions but that didn't work. I'm unsure of what to do next.